# Nested if statements ruby on rails throw error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to apply this, bur the webpage sent me error in `@stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(params[:ticker])` when I write in the form something that does not exist, instead the message. When I don´t write anything or I write the correct characters, the code works ok, just when I write something wrong on purpose for testing, is when this happens. Any advice?

method

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @stock = StockQuote::Stock.new(api_key: 'pk_7716557806964d85bbd63ceab9bbcbb2')
   
    if params[:ticker] == ''
        @nothing = 'Sorry, you forgot to write something, LOL'
    elsif params[:ticker]
        @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(params[:ticker]) 
        if !@stock
            @error = "Sorry, maybe you should try again, the symbol you wrote doesn't exist"
        end
        
    end

   end 

  def about
  end

  def lookup
  end

end
```

html

```
<%= form_tag root_path, :method => 'POST' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'ticker', nil, placeholder: 'Enter Ticker Symbol', size: 50 %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Lookup'%>
<% end %>

<% if @nothing %>
    <%= @nothing %>
<% elsif @stock %>
    <%= @stock.symbol %><br/>
    <%= @stock.company_name %><br/>
    <%= number_to_currency(@stock.latest_price , :unit => "$ ") %>
    <% if @error %>
        <%= @error %>
    <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLQWU.png)

Comment: It seems like you're missing the rest of the `#index` method.

Comment: You are missing two `end` statements in the method `index`

Comment: What's the error that you got?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited with all the lines I was missing in the post

Comment: the error on the top says "Unknown symbol"

Comment: attach screenshot with error

Comment: You need to show the full error

Comment: Done, now is attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message it seems like your assumption of how `StockQuote::Stock.quote` works is incorrect. It seems like `StockQuote::Stock.quote` does not return `nil` if the stock symbol in `params[:ticker]` does not exist but raises an exception.

A quick and dirty workaround might be to change this part

```
elsif params[:ticker]
  @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(params[:ticker]) 
  if !@stock
      @error = "Sorry, maybe you should try again, the symbol you wrote doesn't exist"
  end
end
```

to

```
elsif params[:ticker]
  begin 
    @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(params[:ticker]) 
  rescue => e
    @error = "Sorry, maybe you should try again, the symbol you wrote doesn't exist"
  end
end
```

For more tailored error handling you would need to provide the full error message from your log fil including the stack trace.

Comment: THANKYOU SOOOO MUCH! I spent a lot of time trying to fix it! My error says in log:

Started POST "/" for ::1 at 2021-02-18 23:24:24 -0600
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "ticker"=>"zdfbvzdfbv", "commit"=>"Lookup"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 329ms (Allocations: 3228)


  
RuntimeError (Unknown symbol):
  
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:8:in `index'